# Blender subprocess init help

Tags: python

I am working on a project which uses blender with subprocess. I have been able to get a blender instance to run and output an image through `subprocess.run()` however this is bad for my project because the amount of time it takes for Blender to initialize when I need it to render is super slow and this adds a few seconds onto my few milliseconds of rendering time that usually takes.

To make my needs clear, I need to be able to run a Blender Python script multiple times on the same Blender instance with subprocess without having to deal with the initialization process.

Since the intialization is the problem I saw that something like `Subprocess.Popen()` existed where you can open an instance of a program and keep it running. The only thing which stands in my path to completing this project is knowing how to communicate with Blender while the process is running. Like I said, all I need to do is run a Python script inside Blender multiple times while keeping the same blender instance open.

Here is my script that I have been able to get to run with `subprocess.run()`

```
import subprocess
blender_executable = correct\path
blend_file = correct\path
python_script = correct\path
output_location = correct\path
frame = "0"  #Frame Must Be a String!
#subprocess
subprocess.run([blender_executable, "-b", blend_file, "-P", python_script, "--background", "-o", output_location, "-f", frame, "-noaudio"])
```

Comment: Hello. I don't remember the argument name but you can add an argument to load the defaults settings, it should open faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a socket connection.

Here is an example of a one-sided socket connection. Install as an addon. Put a folder with all the 3 files inside a Blender's `scripts\addons` folder. The operators will appear in the top Edit menu.

`__init__.py`

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "test_socket_connection",
    "author": "unwave",
    "description": "",
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "version": (0, 0, 2),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "category": "Generic"
}


import bpy

from . blender_owner import *

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_OT_init_connection)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_OT_run_command)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_OT_close_connection)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_edit.append(menu_func_1)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_OT_init_connection)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_OT_run_command)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_OT_close_connection)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_edit.remove(menu_func_1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

`blender_owner.py`

```py
import os
import typing

import bpy

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import socket
    import subprocess

DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
THE_SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.join(DIR, 'blender_server.py')


global THE_PROCESS
THE_PROCESS: typing.Optional['subprocess.Popen'] = None

global THE_SOCKET
THE_SOCKET: typing.Optional['socket.socket'] = None


def server_thread(background: bool):
        
        global THE_PROCESS
        global THE_SOCKET

        import json
        import subprocess
        import socket

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socket_:

            host = 'localhost'
            socket_.bind((host, 0))
            port = socket_.getsockname()[1]

            command = [
                bpy.app.binary_path,
                '--factory-startup',
                '-b' if background else '--no-window-focus',
                '-noaudio',
                '--python-exit-code',
                '1',
                '--python',
                THE_SCRIPT_PATH,
                '--',
                '-json_args',
                json.dumps(dict(
                    host = host,
                    port = port,
                ))
            ]

            with subprocess.Popen(command) as THE_PROCESS:

                socket_.listen()

                THE_SOCKET, addr = socket_.accept()
                THE_SOCKET.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, True)

                THE_PROCESS.wait()


class TEST_OT_init_connection(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.test_init_connection"
    bl_label = "test_init_connection"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return THE_PROCESS is None or THE_PROCESS.poll() is not None

    start_mode: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = 'Background', 
        default = True, 
        description = 'Start in the background mode. Non-modal execution only.'
    ) # type: ignore

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return bpy.data.window_managers[0].invoke_props_dialog(self, width = 300)

    def execute(self, context):

        import threading

        threading.Thread(target=server_thread, kwargs=dict(background=self.start_mode), daemon=True).start()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


class TEST_OT_run_command(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.test_run_command"
    bl_label = "test_run_command"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return THE_PROCESS is not None and THE_PROCESS.poll() is None

    command_type: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items = [
            ('print_objects', 'Print objects', ''),
            ('add_cube', 'Add cube', ''),
            ('delete_all', 'Delete all objects', ''),
        ],
        default = 'print_objects') # type: ignore
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return bpy.data.window_managers[0].invoke_props_dialog(self, width = 300)

    def execute(self, context):

        import json

        data = {
            'type': self.command_type
        }

        THE_SOCKET.sendall(json.dumps(data).encode() + b'\0')
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


class TEST_OT_close_connection(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.test_close_connection"
    bl_label = "test_close_connection"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return THE_PROCESS is not None and THE_PROCESS.poll() is None

    def execute(self, context):

        import json

        data = {
            'type': 'kill'
        }

        print('Shutting down...')
        THE_SOCKET.sendall(json.dumps(data).encode() + b'\0')
        THE_PROCESS.kill()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func_1(self, context):
    self.layout.separator()
    self.layout.operator(TEST_OT_init_connection.bl_idname)
    self.layout.operator(TEST_OT_run_command.bl_idname)
    self.layout.operator(TEST_OT_close_connection.bl_idname)
```

`blender_server.py`

```py
import json
import queue
import socket
import threading
import traceback

import bpy

print('SERVER STATING')

def get_args() -> dict:
    import argparse
    import json
    import sys

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-json_args')

    args = sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--') + 1:]
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    return json.loads(args.json_args)


ARGS = get_args()


def print_objects():
    if bpy.data.objects:
        print("I have objects:")
        for obj in bpy.data.objects:
            print(obj)
    else:
        print("Do not have any objects :(")


def add_cube():
    print('Will add a cube.')
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()


def delete_all():
    print('Deleting all objects')
    bpy.data.batch_remove(bpy.data.objects)


jobs_queue = queue.Queue()
sentinel = object()


if bpy.app.background:
    def do_action(func, *args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
else:
    import functools
    def do_action(func, *args, **kwargs):
        bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs))


def working():

    for job in iter(jobs_queue.get, sentinel):
        
        try:
            data: dict = json.loads(job)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            traceback.print_exc()
            print(job)
            continue

        if data['type'] == print_objects.__name__:
            do_action(print_objects)
        elif data['type'] == add_cube.__name__:
            do_action(add_cube)
        elif data['type'] == delete_all.__name__:
            do_action(delete_all)
        elif data['type'] == 'kill':
            jobs_queue.put_nowait(sentinel)
            bpy.app.timers.register(exit)
        else:
            print(job)


def socket_listening(listening_socket: socket.socket):

    truncated_message = None
    message = None

    while listening_socket:

        try:
            message = listening_socket.recv(1024 * 8)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            jobs_queue.put_nowait(sentinel)

            bpy.app.timers.register(exit)
            return
        
        if not message:
            continue

        messages = message.split(b'\0')

        if truncated_message is not None:
            messages[0] = truncated_message + messages[0]
        
        if messages[-1] == b'':
            truncated_message = None
        else:
            truncated_message = messages[-1]

        for message in messages[:-1]:
            jobs_queue.put(message)


try:
    listening_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    listening_socket.connect((ARGS['host'], ARGS['port']))
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    traceback.print_exc()
else:
    threading.Thread(target=socket_listening, args=[listening_socket], daemon=True).start()

    if bpy.app.background:
        working()
    else:
        threading.Thread(target=working).start()


print('SCRIPT END')
```